# Can you chain properties?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I have an automation test that I have switched out most variables for properties which has been working fantastic for me unless i need to chain something.  Here is an example of what I'd like it to look like:

```js
var test = module.exports = {
  outerElement: element(by.cssContainingText('some.div' 'A name'),
  innerElement: $('something.else'),
  clickOnaName: function () {
    this.outerElement.this.innerElement.click();
    },
```

However I have to use this code because chaining doesn't work the way I am using it:

```js
var outerElement = element(by.cssContainingText('some.div'
      'A name');
    var innerElement = $('something.else');

    var test = module.exports = {
        clickOnaName: function() {
          outerElement.innerElement.click();
        },
```

Is there a way for me to do chain or should i just leave those elements as variables

Comment: I think that's not possible. However i guess there's no need to have such a scenario. Can you please provide an example as to where will you be applying such scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please let me know if this helps!

You can use `.element(el.locator())` to extend the elements. You can use multiple selectors at once. You can also hit arrays of elements.

Keep in mind that this kind of chaining of protractor selectors is the same as a  css space child selector, and not as a > selector.
I.e. `$('.parent').$('.child')` will select the same elements as in a css file `.parent .child`, getting ALL children and not just direct children.

```
module.exports = function(){
    this.parent = $('.parent');
    this.child = $('.child');
    this.childOfParent = parent.element(child.locator());

    this.directParentChild = $('.parent').$('.child');

    this.parentArray = $$('.parents');
    this.child = $('.child');
    this.children = parentArray.get(2).element(child.locator());
}
```

Adding in clicks and such should be pretty straightforward from there, `page.childOfParent.click` for example.